# How does more than 1 table in FROM clause work in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to pivot my columns from

```
id, english, math
1,100,200
2,50,100
```

to a table which looks like

```
id, subject, marks
1, english, 100
1, math, 200
2, english, 50
2, math, 100
```

I was playing around with this temp table in BigQuery and I have this code.

```
with marks as (
select 1 as id, 200 as math, 100 as english union all
select 2 as id, 100 as math, 50 as english 
)

, temp as 
(
select 'math' as subject union all
select 'english' as subject
)


select * from marks, temp
```

I did not understand how does BigQuery operate when you mention 2 tables side by side. Does it do some kind of join internally?

[image]

Comment: It's a cross join. So basically it makes a cartesian multiplication for two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does a cross join.
It's what you want:

```
with marks as (
  select 1 as id, 200 as math, 100 as english union all
  select 2 as id, 100 as math, 50 as english 
)
select id, subject, value
from marks
join unnest([struct('math' as subject, math as value), struct('english' as subject, english as value)]) as s
```

Comment: thanks for this, I know BigQuery is fast but what if the input table - `marks` had 20M records in it with 10 subjects. The cross join grows the table very quickly. So is this an optimized solution? Is there a way to check this in BigQuery?

Comment: Melting is not possible with native functions in BigQuery. So you have to use unnest to make it.
On the other hand, BigQuery is really good at scaling. So don't worry about the performance. And I'm working with tables that has billions of rows. It still works, so don't worry about 20M rows, at all.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and does not require any explicit referencing to column names - so generic enough for tables with any number of columns - in this case subjects

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, subject, CAST(marks AS INT64) AS marks
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '[{}"]', ''))) kv,
UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)] AS subject, SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS marks)])
WHERE NOT subject = 'id'
```

if to apply to sample data from your example - output is

```
Row id  subject marks    
1   1   english 100  
2   1   math    200  
3   2   english 50   
4   2   math    100
```